# Python searching email using imap.lib

Tags: python, date, search, imaplib

### Problem:

I'm trying to filter emails by date using `imap4.search(charset, criterion[])` function, but it won't work.

### What I've tried:

Naturally I started printing `data` returned from

```
typ, data = M.search(None, '(SINCE "22-Jun-2021")')
```

`data` returns all emails, which obviously is not what I wanted.
I also tried

```
M.search(None, '(ANSWERED)')
```

It's working fine, 26 emails were filtered out of 1466 emails, but

```
M.search(None, '(SUBJECT "ignore")')
```

won't work, where "ignore" is one of the test email subject I've sent to target email.

These tests proves only search function with a criterion without second parameter works for me, but I still don't understand why search by date or anything isn't working for me. According to RFC file of imap protocol, my syntax is legit.

### My code:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER, 993)
M.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
rsp, data = M.select('INBOX')
typ, data = M.search(None, '(SINCE "22-Jun-2021")'
print(data)
M.close()
M.logout()
```

Comment: What is your server?  There are some really poor implementations of IMAP out there.

Comment: its domain is imap.exmail.qq.com

Comment: It's been a while, but last time i tried it, QQ had a _very_ poor IMAP implementation.  It could be just that the server doesn't support server side searches properly.

Comment: Glad to know, this gonna change my whole work plan since I've finished everything else